# Can 'substantive' code changes be limited by tags?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

So, a lot of edits are basic things like code formatting, spelling, grammar, things like that - not that often really do I see people actually making changes to code.

But sometimes, people do, and sometimes they're useful, and sometimes they're significant changes that should be comments etc. I can tell the difference in areas I know, but in areas far outside what i'm familiar with, I have no idea.

So far, I have been just hitting 'Skip' on those, deferring to someone else who (hopefully) actually knows if it's a valid edit or not.

Is there a way so these aren't shown to me in the first place? Maybe based on my preferred tag list of something?

It's pretty minor, but distinguishing mere code formatting from code editing is pretty easy, and already there are some very smart features in SO, possibly i just missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already done.  The queue will make its best attempt to show you edits related to posts in tags you've actively contributed to.  It will only show you other edits if there are not edits within your tags to show you.  Given that the vast majority of edits do not require domain knowledge to judge, this is fine, as you can skip those few that you don't know enough to judge.

Also note that it would be hard for the system to differentiate code edits from non-code edits simply due to the fact that the vast majority of code edits are formatting only code edits (which generally requires little to no domain knowledge to judge), and they wouldn't be distinguishable from any more significant code edits.

Comment: Do you have any link to your claim? I never saw such behavior. As far as I can tell, it's loading a random suggested edit item from the queue, regardless of tags.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's harder to notice these days with the queue always being so small.  There needs to be a decently sized queue for this to become noticeable.

Comment: But what is your source? I reviewed thousands of edits in the past, and never noticed they belong to tags I was active in.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've seen it mentioned before in discussions of the queue, but not recently.  I doubt I'd be able to find a reference anytime soon.  As I said, if there aren't posts in the tags you're active in you'll see questions from other tags.  With a very small queue, odds are reasonably high that there are either no eligible edits in your tags, or only a few that you will get through quickly, so you still see plenty of edits in tags you're not active in.  When there are larger queues the behavior is much more noticeable.

Comment: Any chance you're confusing this with the homepage (aka Interesting tab) questions list?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope.

Comment: OK, it's not that important, I just hope we're not misleading users here. If you happen to find a source please let me know. :-)

Comment: yeah, I hadn't seen this behaviour either - but with such small queues, you're right, at some point it has nothing relevant to show me anyways, and i might as well just click 'skip' if it's not relevant.

Comment: @Servy - btw, in response to the original, it would be hard to have a completely correct differentiation. But whitespace-only edits and edits that only wrap code into a code block are obviously benign; anything further may require some domain knowledge.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman The way the diff algorithm works formatting edits frequently end up as editing more than just whitespace.  You'd have a very high false negative rate.